# How to run an algorithm every x minutes on a Server?

Tags: java, mongodb, tomcat, server

I've created a clustering algorithm in Java that reads from a collection in a Mongo database, makes its computations and then writes to a new collection in the same database. Now, I need this algorithm to run every 30 minutes in the server. What could I use to do so?

Comment: In addition to @Prakash's answer, I'd recommend to use whatever Task Scheduler your OS platform provides - it will always be better than implementing reoccurring tasks yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using JavaEE, you could use the `@Schedule` annotation.

Take a look at the [API here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/index.html?javax/ejb/Schedule.html). It saves you from using a dependency in your project.

---

Update:

If you're using JavaSE, maybe a [Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/util/Timer.html) can help you.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [quartz scheduler](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/) to schedule your algorithm every 30 mins, You can find a good tutorial for quartz scheduler [here](http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/quartz-scheduler-tutorial/).

Comment: In my experience quartz was always a pain in the ass... But thats just my opinion...